# Remove row elements of a 2d array by value and reindex

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, filtering, reindex

I have this array:

```
$array = [
    ['b', 'd', 'c', 'a', ''],
    ['c', 'a', 'd', '', ''],
    ['b', 'd', 'a', '', ''],
    ['c', 'd', 'a', 'b', '']
];
```

and need to delete (unset?) all elements where value is "c" so that one ends up with:

```
$array = [
    ['b', 'd', 'a', ''],
    ['a', 'd', '', ''],
    ['b', 'd', 'a', '', ''],
    ['d', 'a', 'b', '']
];
```

The element gets removed, and the other elements to shift up. I know that unset does not re-index the array. Cannot get to unset for all multidimensional arrays, but only with one array. Can the arrays be re-indexed afterwards?

The code BELOW removes elements where the value is equal to "c" but the index of the first element is not re-indexed. Can anyone suggest a solution to re-indexing the inner arrays?

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($array as $val)
{
    foreach ($val as $key => $final_val)
    {
        if ($final_val == "$search_value") 
        {
             unset($array[$i][$key]);
        }
    } 
    $i = $i + 1;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect the dimensions of the array to be afterwards? In general it will not be a rectangle. You probably need to look at the concept of **sparse arrays** if you really care that these are 2D, and that some elements are "once" (although even in sparse arrays "gone" really just means "zero"). Could you not set them to NaN instead? What are you really after?...

Comment: Floris - not sure what you mean by that. I am looking for a simple removal of any elements where it has a certain value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code will do what you want:

```
<?php
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
$c = 3;
$d = 4;

$arr = array(
array ( $b, $d, $c, $a, $b),
array ($c, $a),
array ( $b, $d,  $c ),
array( $c, $d, $a, $b, $b)
);
echo "before:\n";
print_r($arr);

foreach($arr as $k1=>$q) {
  foreach($q as $k2=>$r) {
    if($r == $c) {
      unset($arr[$k1][$k2]);
    }
  }
}
echo "after:\n";
print_r($arr);
?>
```

Output:

```
before:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 1
            [4] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 2
            [4] => 2
        )

)
after:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 4
            [3] => 1
            [4] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 2
            [4] => 2
        )

)
```

As you can see, all the `3`'s have gone...

Comment: This answer clearly does not reindex the first row as required by the asker.

Comment: @mickmackusa - if you look at the comments under the question, you can see that "reindexing" is NOT actually what he wants. "I am looking for a simple removal of any elements where it has a certain value". If this didn't do what he wanted, he wouldn't have accepted the answer, I suppose.

Comment: I see that comment as an incomplete summary of the asked question.  The body of the question mentions multiple times that re-indexing is desired.

Answer (score 0):

Search the value in the sub array then unset it.

```
$search = 'c';
$result = array_map(function ($value) use ($search) {
   if(($key = array_search($search, $value)) !== false) {
      unset($value[$key]);
   }
   return $value;
}, $your_array);
```

Or you could use a loop too:

```
// this way change your original array
foreach ($your_array as &$sub_array) {
    if(($key = array_search($search, $sub_array)) !== false) {
        unset($sub_array[$key]);
    }
}
var_dump($your_array);
```

Comment: This answer will remove a maximum of one element per row and does not attempt to reindex the rows after mutating them.

Answer (score 0):

For a sleek functional approach, use `array_map()` to access the rows, then use `array_filter()` or `array_diff()` to remove all elements with the value of `c`.  `array_filter()` might perform slightly better than `array_diff()`, but `array_diff()` is less verbose and can be very easily adjusted to remove multiple blacklisted values.

`array_search()` will not be suitable if the sought value occurs more than once in a given row -- it will only return the key of the first match.

Before returning the mutated row, re-index it with `array_values()`.

Code [(Demo)](https://3v4l.org/2SikV)

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        fn($row) => array_values(array_diff($row, ['c'])),
        $array
    )
);
```