# PHP removing items in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Got this array returned from Google Analytics Reporting API.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ([0] => Downloads [1] => click [2] => Spring 2015 | 1001295 | NO CODE [3] => 1 [4] => 1),
        [1] => Array ([0] => Downloads [1] => click [2] => Spring 2015 | 1001816 |         [3] => 1 [4] => 1), 
        [2] => Array ([0] => Downloads [1] => click [2] => Spring 2015 | 1002500 |         [3] => 1 [4] => 1),
        [3] => Array ([0] => Downloads [1] => click [2] => Winter 2015 | 1004130 |         [3] => 1 [4] => 1),
        [4] => Array ([0] => Downloads [1] => click [2] => Winter 2015 | 1005166 |         [3] => 1 [4] => 1),
        [5] => Array ([0] => Downloads [1] => click [2] => Winter 2015 | 1009161 |         [3] => 1 [4] => 1),
        [6] => Array ([0] => Downloads [1] => click [2] => Winter 2015 | 1009480 |         [3] => 1 [4] => 1),
        [7] => Array ([0] => Downloads [1] => click [2] => Winter 2015 | 1009819 | NO CODE [3] => 1 [4] => 1),
        [8] => Array ([0] => Downloads [1] => click [2] => Fall 2014 | 1009828 |           [3] => 1 [4] => 1),
        [9] => Array ([0] => Downloads [1] => click [2] => Fall 2014 | 1012443 | NO CODE   [3] => 1 [4] => 1),
       [10] => Array ([0] => Downloads [1] => click [2] => Fall 2014 | 1013870 | NO CODE   [3] => 1 [4] => 1),
       [11] => Array ([0] => Downloads [1] => click [2] => Fall 2014 | 1014200 |           [3] => 1 [4] => 1),
       [12] => Array ([0] => Downloads [1] => click [2] => Fall 2014 | 1014378 |           [3] => 1 [4] => 1),
       [13] => Array ([0] => Downloads [1] => click [2] => Fall 2014 | 1014408 |           [3] => 1 [4] => 1),
       [14] => Array ([0] => Downloads [1] => click [2] => Fall 2014 | 1014452 |           [3] => 1 [4] => 1),
       [15] => Array ([0] => Downloads [1] => click [2] => Fall 2014 | 1015367 |           [3] => 1 [4] => 1),
       [16] => Array ([0] => Downloads [1] => click [2] => Summer 2014 | 1015959 |         [3] => 1 [4] => 1),
       [17] => Array ([0] => Downloads [1] => click [2] => Summer 2014 | 1016689 |         [3] => 1 [4] => 1),
       [18] => Array ([0] => Downloads [1] => click [2] => Summer 2014 | 1017426 | NO CODE [3] => 1 [4] => 1),
       [19] => Array ([0] => Downloads [1] => click [2] => Summer 2014 | 1021750 |         [3] => 1 [4] => 1),
       [20] => Array ([0] => Downloads [1] => click [2] => Summer 2014 | 1022956 |         [3] => 1 [4] => 1),
       [21] => Array ([0] => Downloads [1] => click [2] => spring_2015 | 1026419           [3] => 1 [4] => 1),
       [22] => Array ([0] => Downloads [1] => click [2] => spring_2015 | 1026813           [3] => 1 [4] => 1),
       [23] => Array ([0] => Downloads [1] => click [2] => spring_2015 | 1028789           [3] => 1 [4] => 1),
       [24] => Array ([0] => Downloads [1] => click [2] => spring_2015 | 1029245           [3] => 1 [4] => 1),
       [25] => Array ([0] => Downloads [1] => click [2] => spring_2015 | 1032008           [3] => 1 [4] => 1),
       [26] => Array ([0] => Downloads [1] => click [2] => spring_2015 | 1033724           [3] => 1 [4] => 1),
       [27] => Array ([0] => Downloads [1] => click [2] => spring_2015 | 1034546           [3] => 1 [4] => 1),
       [28] => Array ([0] => Downloads [1] => click [2] => spring_2015 | 1035929           [3] => 1 [4] => 1),
       [29] => Array ([0] => Downloads [1] => click [2] => spring_2015 | 1036488           [3] => 1 [4] => 1),
       [30] => Array ([0] => Downloads [1] => click [2] => spring_2015 | 1038064           [3] => 1 [4] => 1),
       [31] => Array ([0] => Downloads [1] => click [2] => spring_2015 | 1043900           [3] => 1 [4] => 1),
       [32] => Array ([0] => Downloads [1] => click [2] => spring_2015 | 1044241           [3] => 1 [4] => 1),
       [33] => Array ([0] => Downloads [1] => click [2] => spring_2015 | 1045560           [3] => 1 [4] => 1),
       [34] => Array ([0] => Downloads [1] => click [2] => winter_2015 | 1045928           [3] => 1 [4] => 1),
       [35] => Array ([0] => Downloads [1] => click [2] => winter_2015 | 1046329           [3] => 1 [4] => 1),
       [36] => Array ([0] => Downloads [1] => click [2] => winter_2015 | 1046504           [3] => 1 [4] => 1),
       [37] => Array ([0] => Downloads [1] => click [2] => winter_2015 | 1048908           [3] => 1 [4] => 1),
       [38] => Array ([0] => Downloads [1] => click [2] => winter_2015 | 1051460           [3] => 1 [4] => 1),
       [39] => Array ([0] => Downloads [1] => click [2] => winter_2015 | 1051466           [3] => 1 [4] => 1),
       [40] => Array ([0] => Downloads [1] => click [2] => winter_2015 | 1052350           [3] => 1 [4] => 1),
       [41] => Array ([0] => Downloads [1] => click [2] => winter_2015 | 1054942           [3] => 1 [4] => 1),
       [42] => Array ([0] => Downloads [1] => click [2] => winter_2015 | 1056467           [3] => 1 [4] => 1),
       [43] => Array ([0] => Downloads [1] => click [2] => winter_2015 | 1057099           [3] => 1 [4] => 1),
       [44] => Array ([0] => Downloads [1] => click [2] => winter_2015 | 1057666           [3] => 1 [4] => 1)
)
```

I need to remove the first 2 members of each array item. How would I do that?

Comment: So you want to remove [0] => Downloads and [1] => Click from each of them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - remove element in multidimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21249041/php-remove-element-in-multidimensional-array)

Comment: @Glorfindel, there's no reason to request a close here, it is different than the one you mentioned. Besides, i have already selected the answer by Rizier123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just loop through each element of your array with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and just return an [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) with the offset of 2.

```
$newArray = array_map(function($v){
    return array_slice($v, 2);
}, $oldArray);
```