# PHP Remove Multidimensional Array Value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have array multidimensional code like this:

```
$array = [
    'fruits' => ['apple','orange','grape', 'pineaple'],
    'vegetables' => ['tomato', 'potato']
];
$eaten = 'grape';
unset($array[$eaten]);
```

and what i need is to delete 'grape' from the array because 'grape' already eaten. how to fix my code to unset the 'grape'?

and my question number two, if it can be unset, is there a way to unset multi value like

```
unset($array,['grape','orange']);
```

thanks for help..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - remove element in multidimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21249041/php-remove-element-in-multidimensional-array)

Comment: Kindly check my updated answer. It might help!!

Answer (score 2):

You can remove `eaten` element by following way. Use [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) you can find `key` at the position of your `eaten` element.

Here below code shows that in any multidimensional array you can call given function.

```
$array = [
    'fruits' => ['apple','orange','grape', 'pineaple'],
    'vegetables' => ['tomato', 'potato']
   ];
$eaten = 'grape';
$array = removeElement($array, $eaten);


function removeElement($data_arr, $eaten)
{
    foreach($data_arr as $k => $single)
    {
        if (count($single) != count($single, COUNT_RECURSIVE)) 
        {
           $data_arr[$k] = removeElement($single, $eaten);
        }
        else
        {
            if(($key = array_search($eaten, $single)) !== false)
            {
               unset($data_arr[$k][$key]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $data_arr;
}
```

**P.S.** Please note that you can [`unset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) multiple elements in single call. But the way you are using `unset` is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `unset()` i suggest you to create a new Array after removal of required value benefit is that, your original array will remain same, you can use it further:

**Example:**

```
// your array
$yourArr = array(
                'fruits'=>array('apple','orange','grape', 'pineaple'),
                'vegetables'=>array('tomato', 'potato')
                );
// remove array that you need
$removeArr = array('grape','tomato');

$newArr = array();
foreach ($yourArr as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $finalVal) {
        if(!in_array($finalVal, $removeArr)){ // check if available in removal array
            $newArr[$key][] = $finalVal;
        }       
    }   
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($newArr);
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [fruits] => Array
        (
            [0] => apple
            [1] => orange
            [2] => pineaple
        )

    [vegetables] => Array
        (
            [0] => potato
        )

)
```

**Explanation:**

Using this array `array('grape','tomato');` which will remove the value that you define in this array.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it.

```
$array = [
    'fruits' => ['apple','orange','grape', 'pineaple'],
    'vegetables' => ['tomato', 'potato']
];

$unset_item = 'grape';

$array = array_map(function($items) use ($unset_item) {
    $found = array_search($unset_item, $items); 
        if($found){
            unset($items[$found]);
        }       
    return $items;
}, $array);
```