# How to remove a key of an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I need to remove **[picture_names]** from my `array`. Help me to remove this?

[image]

Comment: [unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)`($array[1]["picture_names"])`

Comment: This question shows little to no research effort on behalf of the OP.

Comment: Please remember to use google and do some research before asking on SO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - remove element in multidimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21249041/php-remove-element-in-multidimensional-array)

Comment: In future, please type your code in rather than attaching an image - makes it much easier to help when it is copy/pastable!

Comment: are you sure you aren't posting private information of some person without their consent? if not, do you think it's acceptable, objectively?

Answer (score 2):

Use [unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) function:

```
unset($array['picture_names']);
```

Comment: Just a note, `unset` is a [language construct, not a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180184/what-is-the-difference-between-a-language-construct-and-a-built-in-function-in). Yes, there is a difference

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with **unset()** function. Documentation **[here.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)**

```
$result = unset($yourArray['picture_names']);
var_dump($result);
```